# Load HTML or jade page into div of HTML or jade page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

In my Node.js project, I have a script (JS) that loads a Jade page into div of another Jade page using `$("#div").load(directory)`. I specified the directory of the jade page I want to load but it only says `CANT GET /page1.jade`. Do I need to add something to my `app.js`? Or maybe my directory is wrong (I tried every combination possible)? (I also tried the same with all pages as HTML instead of Jade and it didn't work either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass as "directory" the route to that page.

Don't think about the serverside directory structure, but think about the **routing** map.

Say you have the following directory structure on your nodejs web app:

```
+ views
  |- index.jade
  |- page1.jade
  |- page2.jade
```

Now say you have this route map - I'm going to use an Express-like structure here

```
app.get('/page100', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/page200', function(req, res){
  res.render('page1');
});

app.get('/page300', function(req, res){
  res.render('page2');
});
```

As you see the routing in this example says:

- if the web browser asks for `page100` serve the index page,
- if asks for `page200` serve `page1`
- if asks for `page300` serve `page2`

In your case, say you want to load dinamically `page2`, you have to pass the right route to jQuery:

```
$('#div').load('/page300');
```

**Note**: the routing can be also parametric and more complex but the logic underneath it's always the same as this example here.